# Nodejs promise async/await not working properly

Tags: node.js, api, promise, async-await

Not getting api response of 3500 records inside the promise method. If I call api using setTimeout(), it is working and getting all the data.

Please find the sample code below, (calling apiCall in async method only)

```
let data = await apiCall();

function apiCall(){
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      let options = {method:'get'}
      fetch('http://example.com/getData',options).then(data => {
         resolve(data);
      });
   });
}
```

Comment: yes rajesh, no problem

Comment: Try adding a catch on that fetch request. Maybe you are getting some error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let data = await apiCall();

function apiCall(){
   let options = {method:'get'};
   return fetch('http://example.com/getData', options);
}
```

try like this and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This line here, `let data = await apiCall();`, is invalid if you're not calling inside `async` function becuase `await` is valid only inside `async` function.

The proper syntax for using `async/await` is:

```
async function myFunc() {
  let result = await getSomething()
  ...
}
```

Also `fetch` API supports `Promise`, so in your code you could do:

```
// note async keyword
async function apiCall(){
  let options = {method:'get'}
  try {
    let response = await fetch('http://example.com/getData',options) // response is also a promise so
    let data = await response.json(); // data contains the result
    console.log(data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
}
```

Say if you do `return data` in your `apiCall` function then the result is also wrapped in `promise` by `async` function. So you'll have to:

`apiCall().then(result => console.log(result))`. And again `async/await` usage is above ^

Comment: I'm using await in async method only. In question I have mentioned that within brackets. I tried the same thing which you have answered.